# Rails Github Action can't fill out action text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, github-actions

Using Rails 6.1.4, the following works locally to fill in a Rich Text (Action Text) in a system test:

```rb
find("trix-editor").set("Something")
```

However, running on a GitHub action, I receive:

`Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible css "trix-editor"`

Changing the code to:

```rb
find("trix-editor", visible: false).set("Something")
```

also works locally, but again fails on GitHub CI with:

`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable`

I have also tried the following:

```rb
find("#unique_element_id").set("Something")
find(:css, ".trix-content").click.set("Something")
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 both locally and on the GitHub CI image. How do I resolve this?

EDIT:

I found that there is some [unmerged Rails code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/actiontext/lib/action_text/system_test_helper.rb#L32) that is supposed to do this.  However, implementing it in my `test_helper` also works locally but fails on CI.  Perhaps I just need to try another CI provider

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wait until element is shown with:

```rb
element = wait.until { driver.find_element(:class => "trix-editor") }
element.click
```

Comment: That didn't seem to help, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a test that passed locally but failed on GitHub with Capybara::ElementNotFound. In my case the test was actually broken but locally I had some old compiled assets lingering around that made it pass anyway. I could resolve this by removing public/assets and public/packs-test.